# How to reference Windows SDK from Windows Store class library?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, class-library

How can I add a reference to the Windows SDK to my Windows Store class library so I can store common controls, etc. in there and reference those classes from other Windows Store apps?

When I try to add a reference, there is nothing to add. Only "System" is included as a reference.

Comment: You cannot use the common controls in a Store app.  You cannot directly reference the SDK from a managed class library, it was made to be used in a C or C++ app.  There are *very* few SDK functions that are allowed in a Store app.

Comment: So for every Windows Store app I have to "duplicate" my common code? I realize I can add the classes as a link, but that is pretty annoying...

Comment: How you got from "Windows SDK" to "duplicate my common code" is quite unguessable.  If you actually meant to reuse code that you now have in a desktop app then, no, forget about it.  No duplication is possible, you have to completely redesign it.  If that's not what you meant then, please, type more than two short paragraphs in your question.

Comment: I clearly said I'm making a common **Windows Store** class library. If I can't do this, those classes that I'm using across multiple Windows Store apps have to be included in each app project instead of referenced in a common project.

Comment: What exactly do you have a problem with? Adding a reference to a library (which one?) from your Windows Store class library? Or adding a reference from your Windows Store app to your Windows Store class library?

Comment: @DamirArh - I don't actually know what happened. Originally I had this Windows Store Class Library and the only reference available was "System" - after reopening the project (?) I have the correct references: .NET for Windows Store Apps, System and Windows. Perhaps a bug in VS2012 or just some weird anomaly. Seems okay now, will try to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Store apps, all references are added by default with the name **.NET for Windows Store apps**.

For other supported libraries (another windows store library, portable library), you need to add reference.

Normal .NET libraries cannot be added.